# Change text on back button in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm using iPhone SDK 3.1.3 and I tried look like that

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

It's not working and nothing effect. So, I tired

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

button text it change and stye it squre. I click it and it's not go to back.

I want to change back button to text @"Back". How to write it ?

I also read in [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835607/how-to-change-text-on-a-back-button) but not work for me.

Comment: Check this

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835607/how-to-change-text-on-a-back-button>

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I change in title and it's OK

```
self.navigationItem.title =@"Back"; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
```