# Variable width title UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, titleview

What I have :

```
+-------------------------------------+
|< Back [ Current Long Title ]        |
```

What I want :

```
+-------------------------------------+
|< Previouse Long [ Current Long...]  |
```

I've tried setting custom `titleView` on my `UINavigationController navigationItem`, I've tried setting up custom `backItem`, but as far I have not reached a satisfying result.
The worst thing, is that, when I try to set the width of `titleView` programatically from my controller It doesn't grow to one side, but  rather keeps it centered.

I also thought about subclassing only the top navigation bar, but couldn't find any example or wrap my head around it.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835607/how-to-change-text-on-a-back-button

Comment: Note the comment about setting it on the 'pushing' view controller, not the 'pushed' view controller (in your case on the 'previous' not the 'current')